# What is the purpose of annotations in Java?

Tags: java, annotations

I understand that annotations serve a purpose to modify code without actually BEING code, such as:

```
@Author(
   name = "Benjamin Franklin",
   date = "3/27/2003"
)
```

But I don't understand how using the annotation is any better/ clearer/ more concise than just saying name = "Benjamin Franklin" ? How does the addition of annotations strengthen the code?

**EDIT:** Sorry for another questoin, but I know that @Override can help prevent/ track spelling mistakes when calling methods or classes, but how does it do that? Does it help the actual program at all?

Comment: The compiler uses the override annotation to ensure you are actually coding what you think you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations are metadata.
`@Override` annotation is used to make sure that you are overriding method of a superclass and not just making a method with the same name. Common mistakes here consist of:

- spelling the method's name wrong
  `equal(Object o)` instead of `equals(Object o)`
- putting different set of arguments

  MyString extends String { public boolean equals(MyString str) {} }

`equals(MyString str)` is not overriding the method `equals(Object o)` and therefore will not be used by standard Java comparators (which is used in some standard functions, such as `List.contains()` and this is prone to error situation).
This annotation helps compiler to ensure that you code everything correctly and in this way it helps program.

`@Deprecated` annotation doesn't make program not to compile but it makes developers think about using the code that can and/or will be removed in a future releases. So they (developers) would think about moving onto another (updated) set of functions. And if you compile your program with the flag `-Xlint` compilation process will return with an error unless you remove all usages of deprecated code or explicitly mark them with annotation `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`.

`@SuppressWarnings` is used to suppress warnings (yes, I know it's Captain Obvious style :)). There is a deprecation suppression with `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`, unsafe type casting with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and some others. This is helpfull when your project compiler have a compilation flag `-Xlint` and you cannot (or don't want to) change that.

There are also annotation processors that you integrate into your program build process to ensure that program code meets some sort of criteria. For example with IntelliJ Idea IDE annotation processor you can use `@Nullable` and `@NotNull` annotations. They show other programmers when they use your code so that can transfer null as a certain parameter to a method or not. If they transfer null it will cause exception during compilation or before executing a single line method's code.

So annotations are quite helpful if you use them to their full potential.

Comment: what is the difference between optional annotations like `@FunctionalInterface` vs `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` which actually system considers and updates its flags?

I thought annotations are used to tell the use what this is, `@Entity`, `@Consumer`, `@Configuration` etc. System doesn't care about these names right? Is there a term for these?

Comment: All of that could be done with normal language features. In fact, many of Java’s existing features could be considered annotations. Like writing “public” in front of a class/method. … Might aswell just say `public static deprecated nowarn myMethod()` … Annotations seem like merely a duplicate of a feature because the designers forgot they already had something for that. … Correct me if I’m missing anything here …

Answer (score 6):

Annotations are just metadata. On their own they serve little to no purpose. There must be an annotation processor, either at the compiler or run time level that uses them for something.

With an annotation like

```
@Author(
   name = "Benjamin Franklin",
   date = "3/27/2003"
)
```

for example, some annotation processor might read it with reflection at run time and create some log file that this author wrote whatever it's annotating on that date.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are most likely used by other programs. Examples include:

@Override
IDE (compiler?) ensures that the signatures match

@Deprecated
IDE marks occurences, compiler warning

@FXML
JavaFX can use these annotations initialize variables in a controller class when an .fxml File is inflated (see http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm). They are also used by JavaFX Scene Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations works as a way to marking up the code. Several frameworks uses it, and some others make a great use of it producing your own.

Besides, is important to understand that annotations are the equivalent to meta-data, but is much more than that, since it works as a tag language for the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Java @Annotation**

`@Annotation`(from `Java 5`) adds a metadata which are used for instruction in compile, deployment and run time. It is defined by `RetentionPolicy`

`RetentionPolicy` defines a lifetime

- `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE`: It is visible only in **compile** time(`@Override`, `@SuppressWarnings`, `@StringDef`). For example it can be used by `apt` to generate some code
- `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`: It is visible in **compile and deployment** time(`.class`). For example it can be used by `ASM` or Java AOP paradigm like AspectJ
- `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`: It is visible in **deployment and run** time. For example it can be used `java reflection` using getAnnotations(). `Dagger 2` uses `@Scope` annotation

**Create a custom Annotation**

```
@Retention(<retention_policy>) //optional
@Target(<element_type>) //optional to specify Java element like, field, method...
@Inherited // optional will be visible by subclass 
@Documented // optional will be visible by JavaDoc
@interface MyAnnotation {
    //attributes:
    String someName();
}
```

using

```
@MyAnnotation(someName = "Alex")
public class SomeClass {
}
```

Comment: This does not contain a single word about what was asked. You merely described what it is. OP asked, _why_ it is.