# What does the '@' symbol mean in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have no experience in objective C, so I'm having trouble with some of the notation. In my "AppDelegate.swift" file, there is a "@UIMainApplication" at the top. What does this mean?

Also, if possible, could you please give me the "equivalent" statement (if it exists) in C++?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

Well, you picked a rather complicated one. The `@` merely means that this is an *attribute* - a special marker or signal to the compiler, as [Apple explains here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html). But `@UIApplicationMain` is a particularly profound attribute! It substitutes for the entire `UIApplicationMain` implementation that lies at the heart of a C / Objective-C application, in the *main.m* file (as [I explain here](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch06.html#_code)):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,
                                 NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

That is the main entry point of the app, implementing the entire launch-and-run code that *is* the running application. You *can* do something like that in Swift — a *main.swift* file with the Swift equivalent of that code — but Swift saves you the trouble by letting you designate your app delegate class with the `@UIApplicationMain` attribute.

If you start a project as an Objective-C or Objective-C++ project, the template will give you a *main* file containing the `main` implementation, so there's no need to do anything special in this regard.

Comment: Thx. I had read: [The App Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) some time ago, and recently went looking for `main` in my Swift project... obviously, couldn't find it.

Comment: @benc you _can_ remove `@UIApplicationMain` and provide your own _main.swift_ file if you like, as here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch06p297main/bk1ch06p297main/main.swift But I can think of no reason to do this nowadays.

Answer (score 11):

Keywords starting with an @ are instructions to the compiler – for example, in view controllers you use `@IBOutlet` to identify variable declarations that relate to connections within the visual interface build (a storyboard or XIB file – the 'IB' prefix stands for 'Interface Builder', which was the old name for the part of Apple's design tools that provided the GUI for visually creating interfaces).

Put simply, `@UIApplicationMain` is an indicator for Swift applications that indicates which object is your application's main application delegate file. In Objective-C application templates, you would have a trivial `main.m` C file which sets the application delegate. With Swift, that trivial implementation becomes a single directive.

In both cases, the trivial implementation can be replaced with something more complex if need be – but in most apps there is no need for anything else, and indeed if you're only just starting out in Swift, the chances of you needing a non-trivial implementation are most likely to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift attribute**

[Swift attribute](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html) is a **marker** which is used by compiler to execute some specific logic. It is a kind of Aspect Oriented approach

```
@<attribute_name>(<attribute_arguments>)
```

@NSApplicationMain, [[@UIApplicationMain]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61504620/4770877) - generates main.swift 
[[@objc vs @objcMembers]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217057/4770877) 
[[@noescape vs @escaping]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60990583/4770877) 
[[@autoclosure]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62265997/4770877) 
[[@testable]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67344537/4770877)

There are some private attributes like `@_exported`, `@inline`...

[[Objective-C property attributes]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66282129/4770877)

[[Java annotation]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61189426/4770877)