# When to use @objc in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, selector, private

In Swift, I see some methods like:

```
@objc private func doubleTapGestureRecognized(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
```

I was wondering, when to use @objc? I read some documents, but they are saying when you want it to be callable in Objective-C, you should add @objc flag

However, this is a private function in Swift, what does the @obj do?

Comment: nice question !!!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

private mean it visible only in Swift.
so use @objc to visible in Objective-C.
If you have a func to selector a private func in swift, it is required.

> The @objc attribute makes your Swift API available in Objective-C and the Objective-C runtime.

See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html

Comment: so for `@objc private func doubleTapGestureRecognized`, what's the point to have both @objc and private? Are you saying Objective-C classes can overwrite doubleTapGestureRecognized?

Comment: I guess, because in obj-c you can overwrite any method anyway.

Comment: Not sure how this answer is right & answers his Q. The ans provided here is already in his Q itself "but they are saying when you want it to be callable in Objective-C, you should add \@objc flag" , his main Q is "This is a private function in swift, what does the \@obj do?"

Comment: Links break. Especially into Apple documentation. Please consider extracting the key elements from the documentation here.

Answer (score 77):

Another late answer, but none of the existing answers on this question really answer the OP's question, which is: why the heck would you need to use `@objc` on a `private` class member, if `@objc` is there for interaction with Objective-C, and the member in question is private, meaning that even if you have Objective-C code in your project, it shouldn't be able to see the member anyway?

The reason is that, because many of the frameworks are written in Objective-C, sometimes Objective-C features are needed to interact with certain APIs.

For example, suppose I want to register for a notification via `DistributedNotificationCenter`:

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                  selector: #selector(somethingHappened(_:)),
                                                  name: someNotification,
                                                  object: nil)
```

For this to work, we need to be able to get the selector for the `somethingHappened` method. However, selectors are an Objective-C concept, so if the method is not visible to Objective-C, it does not have a selector. Therefore, even if the method is private and should not be called by arbitrary outside code, it will need an `@objc` in order for the `DistributedNotification` code, which is written in Objective-C, to be able to call it via its selector.

Another common case where `@objc` is needed is to support Key-Value Coding (KVC), especially on macOS, where KVC and KVO are used to implement Cocoa Bindings. KVC is, like many other systems in Cocoa, implemented in Objective-C, which has the effect of requiring KVC-compliant properties to be exposed to the Objective-C runtime. Sometimes, it makes sense for KVC-compliant properties to be private. One example is when you have a property that affects other properties:

```
@objc private dynamic var originalProperty: String

@objc private static let keyPathsForValuesAffectingDependentProperty: Set<String> = [
    #keyPath(originalProperty)
]
@objc public var dependentProperty: String { return changeItSomehow(self.originalProperty) }
```

In this case, our actual stored property is private, but the dependent property, which we *do* expose to outside code, needs to send its notifications when the private property is updated. By marking the private property as `@objc`, we can easily do that by setting up a KVC dependency—otherwise, we'd have to write code to manually send the notifications in the private property's `willSet` and `didSet` handlers. In addition, the static property that informs the KVC system that `dependentProperty` is dependent on `originalProperty` needs to be exposed to Objective-C so that the KVC system and find it and call it, but it's not relevant to clients of our code.

Also, a view controller in a macOS app that updates controls in its view using Cocoa Bindings as an implementation detail may make certain private properties KVC-compliant in order to bind those controls to them.

So as you see, there are times when a method or property may need to be exposed to Objective-C in order to interact with the frameworks, without necessarily needing to be visible to clients of your code.

Answer (score 25):

**@objc** / **dynamic**

It's for compatibility: Once you import your Swift file/code into Objective-C based project.

And use that if you want your property/method to be accessed by Objective-C code or class.

Most of the time it happens when you are sub classing a Swift class of Objective-C base class.

> A Swift class or protocol must be marked with the **@objc** attribute to
>   be accessible and usable in Objective-C. This attribute tells the
>   compiler that this piece of Swift code can be accessed from
>   Objective-C. If your Swift class is a descendant of an Objective-C
>   class, the compiler automatically adds the @objc attribute for you.

Here apple documentation that says about `@objc`.

[Using Swift from Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/migrating_your_objective_c_code_to_swift)

[Language Interoperability
  Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_36)

**Links Updated:**
Looks like the links has been updated by apple.

Answer (score 13):

@objc is a class attribute, so you use

```
@objc public class MyClass
```

It exposes the class' methods to Objective C classes, so you'll only use it if your class contains public functions

Answer (score 8):

A late answer, but this `@objc` behavior is changing slightly as of Swift 4 (which came out in Xcode 9, which was generally released 10 days ago).

In Swift 4, some inference cases of `@objc` are removed. This just means in some additional cases where before the `@objc` header was inferred by the Swift compiler, it's in Swift 4 not inferred.

Read more at the Swift evolution proposal about [this change](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md)

As has been mentioned, in general `@objc` is to expose certain methods to the Objective-C runtime, which is part of Swift's interoperability the language.

Comment: so this should be the reason why after updating to Swift 4 some variables are not accessible from ObjC right? With Swift 3.X there was no need to add `@objc`

Comment: oh ok, it is always good to double check with someone else, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift @objc vs @objcMembers**

`@objc` exposes a declaration to `Objective-C runtime`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66269619/4770877). Let's take a look at `#selector`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236656/4770877) feature of Swift to use an Objective-C runtime. In this case you are able to define your Swift `@objc private func`[<sup>[More]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60954443/4770877)

To use Swift's functions from Objective-C:

1. Swift's class should be extended from **`NSObject`**
2. Mark Swift's:

a. `@objcMembers` **class** only - to expose **all** `public` **constructors**, **fields** and **methods**. Also it is applicable for subclasses

b. `@objc` **class/enum/protocol** (except **struct**)[<sup>[Named Type]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219141/4770877)

- `@objc` **class**(optional) - to expose a **default** `public init()`. Or `@objc(<custom_name>)` to setup a custom name for class.
- `@objc` **constructors**, **fields** and **methods** - to expose them selectively

Swift's method will be available by the next naming:

```
<swiftName>With<firstArgument>:<secondArgument>:
```

For example:

```
public func printHelloWorld(arg1: String, arg2:String)
//is reached through: 
[someObject printHelloWorldWithArg1: arg2:];
```

[[`@objc` and `dynamic`]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60937714/4770877)