# importing swift framework into a objective-c project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks

I am importing swift framework into objective-c project like this:

```
@import MyFramework;
```

The problem is that only some of the classes are recognized by the class i am importing the framework.

The class which is recognized:

```
public class RecognizedClass:UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandle 
 { ... }
```

The class which is not:

```
public class VeediUtils
{ ... }
```

They are both public so why the first is recognized in the workspace and the other not?

Also i see in the header file MyFramework-Swift.h that a class

```
@interface RecognizedClass : UIViewController <WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler>
```

Appear while the other dont

Why is that?

Also to point that this same procedure work when i am importing swift framework to swift project

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To access a swift class in objc, that is not inherited from NSObject you need to:

@objc public class VeediUtils

> A Swift class or protocol must be marked with the @objc attribute to be accessible and usable in Objective-C. This attribute tells the compiler that this piece of Swift code can be accessed from Objective-C. If your Swift class is a descendant of an Objective-C class, the compiler automatically adds the @objc attribute for you.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 34):

If you previously configured Project for integrating with Swift and want to use Swift Dynamic Framework, you have to import it like this way (replace {value} with appropriate names depending on your Project):

```c
#import <{MyFramework}/{MyFrameworkMainClass}-Swift.h>  
#import "{YourProjectTargetName}-Swift.h"
```

EDIT:

If your framework has `Defines Module` set to `true`, then you can import it like this:

```c
@import MyFramework;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `@objc` to the declaration of the `VeediUtils` class, or make it inherit from `NSObject`. Otherwise it won't be visible to Objective-C.

In your case, `RecognizedClass` is recognized because it is a subclass of `UIViewController`, which is a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: sooner or later `UIViewController` will also be a Swift class

Answer (score 3):

**Using Swift Classes in Objective-C**

If you are going to import code within an App Target (Mixing Objective-C and Swift in one project) you should use the next import line `#import "<#YourProjectName#>-Swift.h"` to expose Swift code to Objective-C code [<sup>[Mixing Swift and Objective-C code in a project]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217109/4770877)

In this post I will describe how to import Swift framework to Objective-C code

### Objective-C consumer -> Swift dynamic framework

Xcode version 10.2.1

### Create a Swift framework

Follow [`Create Swift framework`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216060/4770877)

Expose Swift API. To use Swift's functions from Objective-C[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217057/4770877)

### Objective-C consumer

Follow [`Using Swift framework`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216060/4770877)

Import module to the Objective-C client code[<sup>[module_name]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57517400/4770877)

```
@import module_name;
```

[[More examples here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)