# Using Swift library in an Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working in an Objective-C, iOS project, I used [danielgindi Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library which is a Swift library. I downloaded it using Cocoapods.

I am trying to import the library files into my Objective-C files using `'projectName-Swift.h'` as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c)  but  I faced an error:

> 'projectName-Swift.h' file not found

Comment: Did you checked usage section of Charts lib?
When using Swift in an ObjC project:
You need to import your Bridging Header. Usually it is "YourProject-Swift.h", so in ChartsDemo it's "ChartsDemo-Swift.h". Do not try to actually include "ChartsDemo-Swift.h" in your project :-)
Under "Build Options", mark "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code"

Comment: @DavidV I noticed this and imported 'myprojectName-Swift.h'
and I set "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" to yes.
I faced the same issue

Answer (score 10):

If you have installed Swift library using cocoapods

To import Library in Objective C Code 
Use 
in Objective C

```
@import frameworkname;
```

In Swift

```
@import frameworkname
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using cocoa pods try to make sure you have use_frameworks! in your cocoa pods pod file, otherwise the Swift Framework wont work. Also look at this for any other issues that may pop up: [link](https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/)

Comment: The swift framework has to explicitly support Objective C as is mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099596/importing-swift-framework-into-a-objective-c-project Could this be your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For making the bridging header visible to your compiler you need a little setup

> 1. Go to your Project Build Settings
> 2. Search for *bridging header*
> 3. Add the path to your
>      .h file (usually ProjectName/ProjectName-Swift.h)