# '#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C

Tags: xcode, swift

The new Xcode 7.3 passing the parameter via addTarget usually works for me but in this case it's throwing the error in the title. Any ideas? It throws another when I try to change it to @objc

Thank you!

```
cell.commentButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedViewController.didTapCommentButton(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

The selector it's calling

```
func didTapCommentButton(post: Post) {
}
```

Comment: What does the class declaration line of FeedViewController look like? How is didTapCommentButton declared? What error do you get when you add @objc?

Comment: Update, I edited my post. I'm away from the computer it's on right now so I forget the exact error message but it was one of those situations where XCode tells me to add it then throws an error on its own decision.

Comment: Does your class declare `@objc`, or is it a subclass of `NSObject`?

Comment: Can you try removing the parentheses? It's unusual considering you shouldnt call a function in a selector.

Comment: This solved my problem in a second
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/36963058/1685165](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36963058/1685165)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

In my case the function of the selector was `private`. Once I removed the `private` the error was gone. Same goes for `fileprivate`.

**In Swift 4**
You will need to add `@objc` to the function declaration. Until swift 4 this was implicitly inferred.

Comment: In addition to `fileprivate`.

Comment: @hstdt, so if you set, `fileprivate` will it solved?

Comment: @Hemang, no, @hstdt means that neither `private` nor `fileprivate` will work

Comment: Making the func with dynamic is more appropriate than removing private/fileprivate.

Comment: Add @IBAction as well.

Answer (score 59):

You need to use the `@objc` attribute on `didTapCommentButton(_:)` to use it with `#selector`.

You say you did that but you got another error. My guess is that the new error is that `Post` is not a type that is compatible with Objective-C. You can only expose a method to Objective-C if all of its argument types, and its return type, are compatible with Objective-C.

You could fix that by making `Post` a subclass of `NSObject`, but that's not going to matter, because the argument to `didTapCommentButton(_:)` will not be a `Post` anyway. The argument to an action function is the **sender** of the action, and that sender will be `commentButton`, which is presumably a `UIButton`. You should declare `didTapCommentButton` like this:

```
@objc func didTapCommentButton(sender: UIButton) {
    // ...
}
```

You'll then face the problem of getting the `Post` corresponding to the tapped button. There are multiple ways to get it. Here's one.

I gather (since your code says `cell.commentButton`) that you're setting up a table view (or a collection view). And since your cell has a non-standard property named `commentButton`, I assume it's a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. So let's assume your cell is a `PostCell` declared like this:

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var commentButton: UIButton?
    var post: Post?

    // other stuff...
}
```

Then you can walk up the view hierarchy from the button to find the `PostCell`, and get the post from it:

```
@objc func didTapCommentButton(sender: UIButton) {
    var ancestor = sender.superview
    while ancestor != nil && !(ancestor! is PostCell) {
        ancestor = view.superview
    }
    guard let cell = ancestor as? PostCell,
        post = cell.post
        else { return }

    // Do something with post here
}
```

Comment: If i want to use it with global function? `@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes`

Comment: You cannot use it with a global function.

Answer (score 8):

Try having the selector point to a wrapper function, which in turn calls your delegate function. That worked for me.

```
cell.commentButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wrapperForDidTapCommentButton(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

-

```
func wrapperForDidTapCommentButton(post: Post) {
     FeedViewController.didTapCommentButton(post)
}
```

Comment: Worked for me! still not sure why this is necessary but I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

As you know `selector`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236656/4770877) says that `Objective-C runtime`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217057/4770877) should be used. Declarations that are marked as `private` or `fileprivate` are not exposed to the Objective-C runtime **by default**. That is why you have two variants:

1. Mark your `private` or `fileprivate` method declaration by `@objc`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217057/4770877)
2. Use `internal`, `public`, `open` method access modifier[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905233/4770877)