# NSSortDescriptor with Selector for CloudKit in Swift

Tags: swift, selector, cloudkit, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to sort the results of a CloudKit query (A CKRecord with a String full of text) using a NSSortDescriptor.  I would like to sort it by relevance (i.e. how often keywords appear in said text).  I am trying to do this with a Selector pointing to a function that will decide what text is most relevant.

When I try to do this, Xcode keeps making me add @obj to the front of the selector and function.  The selector is not correctly taking the perimeters.

Is this possible in pure swift, or do I need to use Objective-C?
If so, what should the perimeters look like?

note:  I am not opposed to using Objective-C if I have to, I have just never done it before.

Comment: [Selectors are a feature of the Objective-C runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962854/swift-wants-argument-of-selector-to-be-exposed-to-objective-c).

Comment: I tried this, but it does not call the selector