# No method declared with Objective-C method

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm attempting to create an instance of `Timer` in my Swift 3 model. In short, my code looks something like this:

```
class Foo {
    var timer = Timer()

    func ping() {
        print("Pong!")
    }

    func startPing() {
        timer.invalidate()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.ping), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

This errors out with: `1: Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'ping()' that is not exposed to Objective-C`

When I changed `timer` initialization to: `timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0, target: self, selector: Selector("ping"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)` I get No method declared with Objective-C selector 'ping'`

What is wrong here?

Comment: You meant to say `Selector("ping")` in your second version right?

Comment: @Keiwan I did - made the edit, thanks

Comment: No problem. Does this answer you question? -> [Swift wants argument of #selector to be exposed to Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962854/swift-wants-argument-of-selector-to-be-exposed-to-objective-c)

Comment: @Keiwan It does, I don't know how I missed that. Should I delete this question since that answers it? Or should you answer it below and I give you credit?

Comment: @randombits no don't delete it, just flag it as duplicate... perhaps another person would search something similar to your title and find yours easier—which will then be lead to another question

Comment: @randombits Yeah, I'd say just give it a close vote instead of deleting it. There's not really a point in me giving an answer here that you can also find below the other question.