# Swift nstimer accessing function other class

Tags: swift, class, nstimer

Having trouble running the function in a different class as a selector for NStimer.

```
class VariClass
{
  func updateUILoop()
    {
         print("updating UI")
    }
}
```

In the app delegate I have

```
let values = VariClass()
```

In the appdelegate I have.

```
let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: NSDate(), interval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(values.updateUILoop), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The function works perfectly if I run it manually.

```
getvalues.updateUILoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `NSTimer` to invoke `func updateUILoop` on the `values` object, so the target for timer's callback should be `values`, not `self`:

```
let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: NSDate(), interval: 5, target: self.values, selector: #selector(VariClass.updateUILoop), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: I get this error. "Argument of '#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C".

Comment: @nyitguy [Use `@objc` on the function from which you make a selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36818083/335858)

Comment: @nyitguy I am not sure about the reason behind the `@objc` marker. My only guess is that selectors are kept in Swift only for Objective-C interoperability. In all other situations they are replaced by closures. Hence, Swift language designers wanted programmers to mark functions eligible for selector constructions with a special tag, to make the intention explicit.