# #selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C swift 3

Tags: selector, swift3

I'm using Xcode 8 and swift 3. 
I have the following error on line "let action":
**#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C**
Any suggestion ?

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellWaze", for: indexPath) as! WazeTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.lbAgence.text = aWAgence[indexPath.row][0] as? String
    let cellLat :Double = aWAgence[indexPath.row][1] as! Double
    let cellLong :Double = aWAgence[indexPath.row][2] as! Double

    cell.bWaze.tag = indexPath.row
    let action = #selector(LaunchWaze(cellLat,longitude: cellLong))
    cell.bWaze.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@objc func LaunchWaze(_ latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "waze://")! as URL) {
        // Waze is installed. Launch Waze and start navigation
        var urlStr = "waze://?ll=\(latitude),\(longitude)&navigate=yes"
        print("url : \(urlStr)")
        //UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: urlStr)!)
    }
    else {
        // Waze is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Waze app
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106")! as URL)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818083/selector-refers-to-a-method-that-is-not-exposed-to-objective-c)

Answer (score 5):

Try to inherit NSObject to your class.

```
class YourClass {
  ...
}
```

to

```
class YourClass: NSObject {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in removing the requirement to add the @objc annotation.

Comment: I think so, that it is not beautiful to add @objc in swift.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot include actual parameters into selectors.

And the method for action target can take only three forms:

[UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol)

> **Listing 1** Action method definitions
>
> ```
>     @IBAction func doSomething()
>     @IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: UIButton)
>     @IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent)
> ```

(I added `_` before `sender`, but it is not mandatory, just you need to create a consistent selector. `UIButton` can be any appropriate `UIControl` subclass, or just `Any` if you do not think of what it should be. `@IBAction` can be replaced with `@objc` when adding the method programatically, in many cases, which is implicitly added.)

So, if you want to pass some info to the action method, you need to put it in `sender` or use some intermediate instance properties.

---

In your case, a quick fix would be something like this.

The selector should be:

```
    let action = #selector(launchWaze(_:))
```

And the method:

```
@objc func launchWaze(_ sender: UIControl) {
    let latitude: Double = aWAgence[sender.tag][1] as! Double
    let longitude: Double = aWAgence[sender.tag][2] as! Double

    //...        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really helpfull.