# NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data returns non nil object but with nil properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I have built a swift framework that includes some model classes and I have been using the framework in another ObjC app without any problems. The app uses `NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver` to store/retrieve data objects from `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myCustomer];
[self.prefs setObject:data forKey:@"mykey"];
```

where `myCustomer` is an object of a swift class from the framework. To retrieve the stored object I do:

```
NSData *data = [self.prefs dataForKey:@"mykey"];
Customer *myCustomer = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

The swift class looks like this:

```
@objc public class Customer: NSObject, Codable {
    @objc public var customerID: String
    @objc public var email: String?
}
```

The problem is that after updating the swift framework recently (I made some changes to some other classes not the Customer), `myCustomer` retrieved from `unarchiveObjectWithData` all its properties are `nil`. **The object itself isn't nil but all its properties are nil**. `myCustomer.email` is nil and `myCustomer.customerID` is nil. When I switch back to the old version of the framework, the code above works fine.

Have been trying various things for the past days and nothing has been working. Minimum deployment for the app is iOS 12 and the framework is written in swift 5.0. Would really appreciate any hints, ideas, or of course answers.

Comment: 1. Try to encode and decode in swift if it works as expected. If 1 - works debug coding keys using for decoding  (override initwithcoder to see actual keys)

Comment: did you move customer to another class/framework?

Answer (score 1):

`Codable` it is not the same as `NSCoding`. For encoding a `Codable` object into a plist file you need to use `PropertyListEncoder`. If you need JSON data just use JSONEncoder. To make your object NSCoding compliant you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980432/swift-3-saving-and-retrieving-custom-object-from-userdefaults/37983027)

Comment: Thanks but the code above did work. I just updated the some classes in my framework and decoding does't work anymore. Why did it work before then?

Answer (score -1):

Just a assumption: does it help to declare the Swift vars dynamic? (See [What does @objc dynamic var mean in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559768/what-does-objc-dynamic-var-mean-in-swift-4))