# Show UIPickerView with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Am trying to show a `UIPickerView` thats already hidden using `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Am trying to add this `GestureRecognizer` to a `UILabel`.

The `UITapGestureRecognizer` doesn't work on taping the `UILabel` once. Any pointers appreciated. Thanks

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource  {

    @IBOutlet var baseCurrency: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var excahngeCurrency: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var dropDown: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var currencyLabel: UILabel!

    var list: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject]()
    var titles: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        currencyLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showpickerView))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        currencyLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        let url:URL = URL(string: "https://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json?app_id=7486951aeb994599a08cd7979bef3c03")!
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in

            switch response.result {

            case.success:

                self.list = response.result.value as! [String: AnyObject]

                for (key, _) in self.list{

               self.titles += [key]

                }

                print(self.titles)

                if (self.titles.count > 0) {

                    self.dropDown.reloadAllComponents()

                    print("test")

                } else {
                    print("there is no data for your picker view")
                }



            case .failure:
                print("error")


            }


        })

    }

    func showpickerView(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){

      print("test")

        //self.dropDown.isHidden = false

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{


        return self.titles[row]


    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.titles.count
    }



    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){


        currencyLabel.text = self.titles[row]
        self.dropDown.isHidden = true


    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: the test is called or not

Comment: else check your label frame

Comment: Do you perhaps have another gesture recognizer in your view controller that may be somehow interfering with this one?

Answer (score 0):

After you assign `tap` a value, add `tap.delegate = self`.

Comment: Hi Clay , thanks, i did add tap.delegate = self , doesn't work still.

Answer (score 0):

try This code after in this line ( tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1)

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Comment: Thanks Vignesh , i ve added tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false after tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Removed the line tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1 in your code.

Comment: tried this , used only tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false and removed tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1. Still doesn't print "test" when i click on the label

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add `@objc`attribute to your `showpickerView(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)` method to use it with `#selector`.

Refer this for more details
['#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818083/selector-refers-to-a-method-that-is-not-exposed-to-objective-c)

Comment: hi , am using swift, adding , but still to check i have added @objc. I have an error in appdelegate

Comment: looks like the error is gone when i build it . I have added                      @objc func showpickerView(_ sender:UIGestureRecognizer)                            it still doesn't print test

Answer (score 0):

First , you fix function like this:

```
func showpickerView(_ sender:**UIGestureRecognizer**){
  print("test")
    //self.dropDown.isHidden = false
}
```

and :

```
let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showpickerView(_:)))
```

You can test again.

Comment: Thanks Ronald. ive updated func and tapgesture to func showpickerView(_ sender:UIGestureRecognizer) and let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showpickerView(_:))) . Still doenst work

Comment: It show or not anything happen? did it print "test"?

Comment: No it doesn't print "test". Am unable to figure out whats wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

This code works to unhide the UIPickerView

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource  {

```
@IBOutlet var baseCurrency: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var excahngeCurrency: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var dropDown: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var currencyLabel: UILabel!

var list: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject]()
var dict: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject]()
var titles: [String] = []
var value: Int = 0

let food = ["app", "ban", "org"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    currencyLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showpickerView(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    currencyLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


let url:URL = URL(string: "https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=7486951aeb994599a08cd7979bef3c03")!
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in

        switch response.result {

        case.success:

            self.list = response.result.value as! [String: AnyObject]

            self.dict = self.list["rates"] as! [String: AnyObject]

             self.value = self.dict["INR"] as! Int

            for (key, _) in self.dict
            {
                self.titles += [key]
            }


            print(self.value)
            print("test")

            print(self.titles)

            if (self.titles.count > 0) {

                self.dropDown.reloadAllComponents()


                print("teest")

            } else {
                print("there is no data for your picker view")
            }



        case .failure:
            print("error")


        }


    })

}
```

@objc func showpickerView(_ sender:UIGestureRecognizer){

```
  print("test")

   self.dropDown.isHidden = false

}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{


    return self.titles[row]


}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.titles.count
}



func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){


    currencyLabel.text = self.titles[row]
    self.dropDown.isHidden = true


}
```