# NStoolbar actions doesn't work

Tags: swift, macos, nstoolbar

Iam trying to set nstoolbar with actions.
I did set delegate etc, but when I click to toolbar item with nsbutton as custom view action doesn't work - same without nsbutton.

BUT, when I add breakpoints AND!!!! write in console po button.acttion it does work :D Without "po button.action" I can't handle this action...

IBActions and IBOutlets doesn't work too...

Please help, I rly don't know what is that.

[image]

Comment: I tried add under button.target - print(button.target) ... nothing

Comment: Are your `button`s going out of scope when you return the toolbar? You could try adding them to a member array like `var buttons = [NSButton]()`

Comment: Please take a look at this answer, hope it helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57912431/7218228