# Project-Swift.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a new Swift project with a few files, I've needed to add some Objc code.

In `Build Settings`, my `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` is `MyProject-Swift.h`

`Product Module Name` and `Product Name` are both MyProject.

---

My `Objective-C Bridging Header` is `MyProject/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h`

The contents of my `Bridging Header` are:

```
#ifndef MyProject_Bridging_Header_h
#define MyProject_Bridging_Header_h

#import "Blakey.h"

#endif
```

`Blakey.h` is pretty simple:

```
@import Foundation;

#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
@class KeyPair;

@interface Blakey: NSObject

- (void)createKeyPairForSeed:(NSString *)seed;

@end
```

And `Blakey.m`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Blakey.h"

@implementation Blakey


- (void)createKeyPairForSeed:(NSString *)seed;
{

}

@end
```

(side note: I'm aware my function returns a void, that will be changed later once this issue is fixed so it returns an actual value)

Why is Xcode throwing an error at the `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"` in `Blakey.h`?

Comment: Why are you importing project-swift.h in your Objective-C file? Are you trying to call a swift function in Objective C file ? If not there is no need to call project-swift.h in your Objective-C file

Comment: I'm trying to access my KeyPair class which is a swift class defined as `@objc final class KeyPair` with an `@objc init`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing Project-Swift.h into a Objective-C class...file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328034/importing-project-swift-h-into-a-objective-c-class-file-not-found)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Project-Swift.h` is a file auto generated by Xcode on successful compilation of the project. Catch here is the word **successful compilation** If your project has any compilation error `Project-Swift.h` file will not be generated. So in a way it becomes a deadlock. Bestway comment out all the lines that have compilation error and then manage to get it compile without any errors. Only after that `Project-Swift.h` will be generated.

Additional information, Once the `Project-Swift.h` file is generated if you open it and if you happened to see that your swift class is not imported there thats because `Project-Swift.h` imports only the classes that extends from **NSObject** So plain Swift classes will not be imported.

**ISSUE:**

You need to import `Project-Swift.h` in .m file and not .h file. So modify your Blakey as

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Blakey.h"
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"

@implementation Blakey


- (void)createKeyPairForSeed:(NSString *)seed;
{

}
```

Finally **remove** `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"` from `Blakey.h`

```
@import Foundation;

@class KeyPair;

@interface Blakey: NSObject

- (void)createKeyPairForSeed:(NSString *)seed;

@end
```

Comment: I've built and run the project many times. The only line throwing the error is `#import MyProject-Swift.h` in my `Blakey.h` file

Comment: @zack-shapiro : Check and lemme know

Comment: @zack-shapiro : Am glad that you solved the problem :) Happy coding

Comment: This is helpful!

Comment: I was struggling with some issue of cycle, this saved my time.

Comment: Yup.... this answer actually nails the ROOT cause of the issue: successful compilation. Can't believe we are still dealing with the BS in 2023. Works for some classes and not for others. Anyway, I get it now and will figure out a work around.Apple.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue and almost ended up spending a whole day trying to figure out what wrong with my app. 
So following the solution that's helped me :

1. Clear derived data
2. Create a class in swift with prefix of @objc for example @objc class mySwiftClass{...}
3. Build the project again

Et voila.. Should work now.

> **Why to add @objc?**
>   this @objc prefix, tells the compiler to generate to your swift class a header file. it will add it to the "MyModule-Swift.h" file

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread, but I had similar issues after adding a new target to a project. I solved it by adding a preprocessor macro (Build Settings -> Apple Clang - Preprocessing) only in said target and then importing the `Swift.h` file conditionally, like this:

```
#if DEV_VERSION
#import "Project_DEV-Swift.h"
#else
#import "Project-Swift.h"
#endif
```

My main target is called `Project` and the new target is `Project DEV` (the space is replaced with an underscore in the import), and the preprocessor macro is called `DEV_VERSION`.

After doing this, both targets build just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode compile time error

```
<product_name>-Swift.h file not found
```

It is a kind of bridge(adapter) between Swift and Objective-C. This file contains Swift's API for Objective-C which was marked [<sup>[@objc and @objcMembers]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217057/4770877).

You can work with types declared in Swift from within the Objective-C code in your project by importing an `Xcode-generated header file`.

The header's name is generated from a `<product_name>-Swift.h`

[[Mixing Objective-C and Swift ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217109/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue whereby it would have this issue for anything other than live.
I resolved the issue by hardcoding "Product module name" & "Product name" to my project name. This avoids the need to have preprocessor logic in every file that includes swift code as demonstrated in Pauli Kettunen's solution.

Comment: How do you do this? Would you provide an example of what file is being edited?