# Why is @Objc used in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

You can add @objc to Swift properties or methods to make them accessibile from Objective-C code. What does this exactly mean? I just want a one liner for this question.

Comment: please see this question answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390378/how-can-i-deal-with-objc-inference-deprecation-with-selector-in-swift-4/44391493#44391493

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The @objc attribute makes your Swift code available in Objective-C and the Objective-C runtime.**

Explaination:

In some cases, you need finer grained control over how your Swift API is exposed to Objective-C. In that case, You can use the @objc(name) attribute to change the name of a class, property, method, enumeration type, or enumeration case declaration in your interface as it’s exposed to Objective-C code.

Check this: [when to use @objc in swift code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795117/when-to-use-objc-in-swift-code)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it happens when you are sub classing a Swift class of Objective-C base class.The **@objc** attribute makes your Swift code available in Objective-C and the Objective-C runtime.