# How some iOS frameworks define Swift protocols using optional without @objc?

Tags: ios, swift

As mentioned in the title, some standard Swift protocols get away with declaring optional requirements without the use of @objc. For example:

```
public protocol UIScrollViewDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) // any offset changes
    @available(iOS 3.2, *)
    optional public func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) // any zoom scale changes
    ...
} 


public protocol UIApplicationDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    ...
    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)
    ...
}
```

The following test failed with the expected compile error due to the missing @objc:

```
public protocol Test: NSObjectProtocol {
    optional func test()
}
```

Comment: Those protocols are written in Objective-C, it just doesn't mark the generated swift headers as `@objc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Optional` protocol method options are available only for `Objective-C` based protocol. `UIScrollViewDelegate` and `UIApplicationDelegate` are Objective-C based protocol. That means you don't need to say its `@objc`. The code which you seeing are bridged file between Objective-C and Swift. So that Swift can have access to those methods. Your protocol `Test` is defined in Swift. Even though you adapting `NSObjectProtocol` the class not exposed to **`Objective-C runtime`**, where the optional option is available.  For this reason, you need to explicitly mention this protocol is exposed to `Objective-C` with `@objc`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is because the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and `UIApplicationDelegate` are Objective-C classes bridged on Swift for you.

The @objc bridges Swift to Objective-C https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795237/440299

Answer (score 0):

#### You can define optional protocol methods by using extensions

important :

**Both protocol and extension should be `public` to be accessible outside of the framework**

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
    func method()
}

public extension MyProtocol {
    func method() {} 
}
```