# Why doesn't referencing outside of a function create retain cycle?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, retain-cycle

Sorry, but I know this is a really dumb question, and I already kind of 'know' the answer, but I need someone to clearly explain to me WHY the answer is what it is.

Lately, I've become a bit obsessed/paranoid about retain cycles and memory leaks in my code, after going through some nightmarish debugging with various memory issues, so in the future I want to nip them in the bud. But after reading and learning a lot about ARC and retain cycles in Swift, although it makes sense, I still don't really have enough of an "intuitive" or natural feel for it, to feel confident that I could spot one, or the lack of one, as I'm coding. So I'm starting to become a little paranoid that I'm creating retain cycles with even basic stuff without realizing it.

So, with that in mind, why doesn't any ordinary function that uses a variable declared outside of it create a retain cycle? For example:

```
    class someClass {
        let a = "I'm letter a"
        let moreLetters = addLetters()
        func addLetters () -> String { 
            let newString = a + "bcdefg"
            return newString
        }
    }
```

In this case, self.moreLetters references the function addLetters, and then the constant self.a is references from within the function addLetters. So would this create a retain cycle if I don't capture weak/unowned self? It seems absurd to me that something this simple would cause a problem...or is it? What about in a nested function, like this:

```
    func someFunction () -> String {
        let a = "I'm letter a"
        func addLetters () -> String { 
            let newString = a + "bcdefg"
            return newString
        }
        let moreLetters = addLetters()
        return moreLetters
    }
```

Would that also create a retain cycle? (Yeah I know this is a convoluted way of performing a simple task; I'm just using this code as an example to make my point).

Have I become super-paranoid and am severely overthinking things?

Comment: `let moreLetters = addLetters()` compiles error.

Comment: In Swift, Strings are value types not reference types so reference cycles will not occur in your examples. Can you rephrase your question using reference types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand how a basic retain cycle is formed. A retain cycle is formed when an object A refers to an object B strongly and at the same time. object B refers to object A strongly as well.

Let's look at your first bit of code.

```
class someClass {
    let a = "I'm letter a"
    let moreLetters = addLetters()
    func addLetters () -> String { 
        let newString = a + "bcdefg"
        return newString
    }
}
```

Actually, a class by itself can never create retain cycles, so let's add some code to create an object:

```
var obj = someClass()
```

First, `a` is initialized to "I'm letter a". After that, `moreLetters` is initialized by calling the method `addLetters`. After the method returns, `moreLetters` is initialized to "I'm letter abcdefg". So far so good.

Now we set `obj` to `nil`:

```
obj = nil
```

If a retain cycle were formed, `obj` would not be deinitialized. However, in actuality, `obj` is deinitialized because nothing holds a strong reference to `obj`!

"Wait a minute!" you say, "But the method `addLetters` still refers to `someClass` because it has `a` in it!" Well, in fact, `addLetters` has already returned! Therefore, everything in it doesn't matter anymore! In addition, `addLetters` belongs to `obj`, which you have already set to `nil`!

Now let's look at your second code:

```
func someFunction () -> String {
    let a = "I'm letter a"
    func addLetters () -> String { 
        let newString = a + "bcdefg"
        return newString
    }
    let moreLetters = addLetters()
    return moreLetters
}
```

A retain cycle does not form because there isn't a even a reference type! There is no objects to be created. All you did in the second code is playing with strings, which are value types. Even if there were a class, a retain cycle would not form because as I said, when you set `obj` to `nil`, all the methods in it "disappear" because methods belong to objects.

---

What about those closures where I must write `[weak self]` or a retain cycle forms?

Those closures are *escaping closures*. Normal closures are deinitialized after they return. However, escaping closures are retained by some object so they are not deinitialized immediately. For more info, see [Escaping Closures in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504180/escaping-closures-in-swift/39504347#39504347)

Comment: Thank you so much - and thanks for humoring my question even though I forgot the simple fact that strings are value types and therefore won't cause a retain cycle!