# Swift @noescape attribute not deprecated?

Tags: swift

I'm still fairly new to Swift. One of the things I've seen many times is the information that in Swift 3 the @noescape attribute has become default and is deprecated. But I don't think that is completely correct.

I've written my own logging library. Here's one of the 30 (actually 36) public logging methods, as of yesterday:

```
   public static func verbose(_ logItem1 : @autoclosure @escaping () -> Any?,
                              _ logItem2 : @autoclosure @escaping () -> Any?,
                              funcFile : StaticString = #file,
                              funcName : StaticString = #function,
                              lineNumber : Int = #line) {
      if .eVerbose >= _thresholdValue {
         doLogging(logLevel: .eVerbose,
                   funcFile: funcFile, funcName: funcName, lineNumber: lineNumber,
                   logItem1, logItem2)
      }
   }
```

And here's the signatures for the private methods that get called:

```
   private static func doLogging(logLevel : ELogLevel, funcFile : StaticString,
                                 funcName : StaticString, lineNumber : Int,
                                 _ logItemClosures : () -> Any?...) {
...
      let logItemsFormatted = formatLogArguments(logItemClosures)
...
   }

   private static func formatLogArguments(_ logItemClosures : [() -> Any?])
                                         -> (messageText : String?, errorText : String?) {
...
   }
```

The closures are all evaluated in the formatLogArguments() method.

My use of "@autoclosure @escaping" on the "log item" parameters was inspired by looking at several open source logging libraries on GitHub. (XCGLogger looks awesome.)

But today I was reading more about closures, and I got to thinking - these closures are not really "escaping", they all get evaluated (or not) before the outer log method returns. So I tried removing the @escaping attributes from all of the log methods. The Swift compiler rewarded me with 30 error messages.

Then, just for the heck of it, I changed the signatures of the two private methods, as follows:

```
   private static func doLogging(logLevel : ELogLevel, funcFile : StaticString,
                                 funcName : StaticString, lineNumber : Int,
                                 _ logItemClosures : @noescape () -> Any?...) {
...
   }

   private static func formatLogArguments(_ logItemClosures : [@noescape () -> Any?])
                                         -> (messageText : String?, errorText : String?) {
...
   }
```

Now the Swift compiler is happy and my test program runs OK.

So maybe @noescape still exists and is useful?

(I haven't tried to analyze the output from the compiler to see if it has been optimized or not - my Swift skills aren't up to that yet.)

Comment: @noescape is the implicit behaviour. The keyword is deprecated, but the behaviour you get by writing it or not, is that your closure does NOT escape from the scope of the method.