# Swift @escaping only applies to non-null function args?

Tags: ios, swift

I've never really understood **when** to use `@escaping` in Swift. I understand what it does (i.e. the difference between escaping and non-escaping closures), but tbf I've always been relying on Xcode to tell me when to add the modifier to my argument.

My question is, why is it the case that `@escaping` only applies to non-nil closures? This is what I mean:

```swift
func someFunc(someArg: Int, callback: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    ...
    }
}
```

In the above, if I don't add `@escaping` Xcode gives me an error. However, if I make `callback` optional like the following, *keeping* `@escaping` results in Xcode error:

```swift
// This is wrong (Xcode complains about @escaping)
func someFunc(someArg: Int, callback: @escaping ((Error?) -> Void)?) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    ...
    }
}
```

Why is that? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you may know, closure parameters, by default, cannot escape. You have to add `@escaping` to allow them to escape. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504180/escaping-closures-in-swift/39504347) for what it means for a closure to escape.

A more accurate wording would be that closures in *function parameter position* are non-escaping by default. As you know `((Error?) -> Void)?` is syntactic sugar for `Optional<(Error?) -> Void>`. Here, the closure type is not in the "function parameter position". It is used as the generic argument of the generic type `Optional`. This is just my opinion, but don't you think `@escaping Optional<(Error?) -> Void>`  seems to mark the *optional* as "escaping"?

For a more extreme case, what about tuples? How can I mark only the first item in a pair of closures as escaping? Also, if I have a `T<(Error?) -> Void>`, is it guaranteed that it would definitely store an instance of a closure? I mean, it's *just* a generic type:

```
class Foo<T> {}

let a: Foo<(Int) -> Int> = Foo()
```

What should `@escaping` do on this struct then?

Finally, hasn't a closure that is wrapped in an `Optional` *already* escaped to that `Optional`?

Perhaps because that is too many things to design, implement and test, the Swift team just made all closures in optionals and tuples, as well as other generic types escaping implicitly.

See also: [SR-2444](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2444)

Comment: The 2444 link is helpful. I think in the last paragraph you meant ...just made all closures ... escaping by default. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @danqing yep, that’s what I meant. Thanks for spotting it!