# Swift: How can I call my function inside completion body?

Tags: swift, swift4, resolve, completion

I have a predefined function that has a completion param:

```
func checkNotificationEnabled(_ resultBlock : ((Bool)->())? = nil){
    Bool enabled = false

    ... a big block of code that gets enabled value 
    ...
    ... end block

    resultBlock?(enabled)
}
```

I need to get the true/false and pass it to another function:

```
@objc
func isNotificationEnabled(_
    resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock
) -> Void {
    checkNotificationEnabled { (enabled:Bool) in
        resolve(enabled)
    }
}
```

Got the error: *Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'resolve'*

How can I pass `enabled` to `resolve` ?

Comment: Add `@escaping` for the `resolve` parameter: `func isNotificationEnabled(_ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void`

Comment: Ah, I was trying to post an answer and there is a comment already :) Anyways, my answer might help you on 'why' this happens. So I'll leave it as is...

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `RCTPromiseResolveBlock` on `func isNotificationEnabled` to be some block that you're trying to execute with respect to `completion` of `func checkNotificationEnabled`, the completion actually 'escapes' (outlives) the scope of the function, **and the compiler simply complains that your `RCTPromiseResolveBlock` may not be alive (in execution) during the completion callback**

You'll have to mark `@escaping` to the 'resolve' parameter to get around this.

You'll definitely get more clarity when you understand what escaping closures are. Have a look at this question: [Escaping Closures in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39504180/9293498)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- `resolve` argument is passed to a function `checkNotificationEnabled` but is not marked @escaping
- `(Bool)->())? = nil` optional is `nil` by default, so no need to assign nil
- `(Bool)->()` this is equal to more readable version `Void`.

---

```
typealias ResultBlock = (Bool) -> Void
func checkNotificationEnabled(_ resultBlock: ResultBlock?) {
    var enabled = false

    ... a big block of code that gets enabled value 
    ...
    ... end block

    resultBlock?(enabled)
}

@objc
func isNotificationEnabled(_
    resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    checkNotificationEnabled { enabled in
        resolve(enabled)
    }
}
```

**Escaping closures**

> A closure is said to escape a function when the closure is passed as
>   an argument to the function, but is called after the function returns.
>   When you declare a function that takes a closure as one of its
>   parameters, you can write @escaping before the parameter’s type to
>   indicate that the closure is allowed to escape.
>
> One way that a closure can escape is by being stored in a variable
>   that is defined outside the function. As an example, many functions
>   that start an asynchronous operation take a closure argument as a
>   completion handler. The function returns after it starts the
>   operation, but the closure isn’t called until the operation is
>   completed—the closure needs to escape, to be called later.
>   [source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)