# Why its impossible to cast `(()->Void)` to `(()->Void)?`

Tags: ios, swift, lambda

I have a function that accepts a request and an optional callback for a server response:

```swift
static func getData(request: NSMutableDictionary?, callback: ((Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Void)? ) {
    // ...
}
```

I want to write a wrapper over this function in which the parameters are not optional. I did it like this:

```swift
static func getData(id: CLong, callback: ((Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Void) ) {
    getData(request: ["userId" : id], callback: callback)
}
```

The problem is that swift cannot convert type `((Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Void)` to type `((Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Void)?`. And I can't figure out why. After all, we can successfully convert non optional to optional:

```swift
var a = "hello"
var b: String? = a // correct
```

Why can't swift do it? Why does Swift think that Type `((Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Void)` and Type `((Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Void)?` are completely different types, and not optional variations of the same type?

Comment: The rule is an optional variable might be nil and the non-option variable never be nil. In your case, you are trying to set the optional value to non-optional. So, whenever you optional value gets nil there will be an exception. Avoiding that exception swift not letting you cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a closure is wrapped inside an optional, that closure "escapes". If you don't know what "escapes" means, read [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504180/escaping-closures-in-swift/39504347#39504347).

The non-optional closure in the second `getData`, however, is not `@escaping`. So you are trying to make a non-escaping closure *escape*! The error message is kind of confusing here, but if you pass `.some(callback)` rather than `callback` directly, it becomes clear what's happening:

> Converting non-escaping parameter 'callback' to generic parameter 'Wrapped' may allow it to escape

So you should mark `callback` in your second `getData` as `@escaping`:

```
func getData(id: CLong, callback: @escaping ((Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Void) ) {
```