# Converting non-escaping value to 'Any' may allow it to escape error - within not escaping function

Tags: swift, escaping, closures

My question is derived from the following Japanese question.
It's not my question, but I'm trying to  answer the following problem but I cannot find the suitable answer.

https://teratail.com/questions/298998

The question above will be simpled like below.

```
func executetwice(operation:() -> Void) {
    print(operation)
    operation()
}
```

This compiler required to add `@escaping` keyword after `operation:` label, such as

```
func executetwice(operation: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print(operation)
    operation()
}
```

But in fact, it seems that `operation` block does not escape from this block.

Another way,

```
func executetwice(operation:() -> Void) {
    let f = operation as Any
    operation()
}
```

also compiler requires to add `@escaping` keyword. It is just upcasting to `Any`.
In other case, just casting to same type, it seems to be error.

```
func executetwice(operation:() -> Void) {
    let f = operation as () -> Void //Converting non-escaping value to '() -> Void' may allow it to escape
    operation()
}
```

I'm not sure why I need to add `@escaping` keyword with no escaping condition.

Just adding `@escaping` keyword will be Ok, but I would like to know why the compiler required the keyword in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` accepts (a variable number of) `Any` as arguments, so that is why it's saying that you are converting a closure to `Any` when you pass it to `print`.

Many checks are applied on closure-typed parameters to make sure a non-escaping closure don't escape (for what it means for a closure to "escape", read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504180/escaping-closures-in-swift/39504347#39504347)):

```
var c: (() -> Void)?
func f(operation:() -> Void) {
    c = operation // compiler can detect that operation escapes here, and produces an error
}
```

However, these checks are only applied on closure types. If you cast a closure to `Any`, the closure loses its closure type, and the compiler can't check for whether it escapes or not. Let's suppose the compiler allowed you to cast a non-escaping closure to `Any`, and you passed it to `g` below:

```
var c: Any?
func g(operation: Any) {
    // the compiler doesn't know that "operation" is a closure! 
    // You have successfully made a non-escaping closure escape!
    c = operation
}
```

Therefore, the compiler is designed to be conservative and treats "casting to `Any`" as "making a closure escape".

But we are sure that `print` doesn't escape the closure, so we can use `withoutActuallyEscaping`:

```
func executetwice(operation:() -> Void) {
    withoutActuallyEscaping(operation) { 
        print($0)
    }
    operation()
}
```

Casting a closure to its own type also makes the closure escape. This is because `operation as () -> Void` is a "rather complex" expression producing a value of type `() -> Void`. And by "rather complex" I mean it is complex enough that when passing that to a non-escaping parameter, the compiler doesn't bother to check whether what you are casting really is non-escaping, so it assumes that all casts are escaping.

Comment: You should mention https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2827967-withoutactuallyescaping which would be safe to use in the case of `print` (which indeed, doesn't actually escape the closure)

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for quickly and clear answer. I had almost same suppose for this but I didn't have  sufficient evidences. Your answer makes my thought clear. Thanks again. I would like to wait any other answers, and I will summarize these answers and I will post it to the Japanese board.

Comment: @AlexZavatone thank you for additional information. I had knew that but I had not be sure that which case should I use this method. Your comment makes it clear. Just now I tried my code to check how to use withoutActuallyEscaping(_:do:).  Thanks!