# Why the "dependencies" command returns some "FAILED" results for an empty project with just one dependency, JUnit?

Tags: gradle

I have a `build.gradle` like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies{
   compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and when I run `gradle dependencies` I get:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

apiElements - API elements for main. (n)
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation ' instead).
\--- junit:junit:4.12 FAILED

compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- junit:junit:4.12 FAILED

compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
\--- junit:junit:4.12 FAILED

implementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
No dependencies

runtime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'runtimeOnly ' instead).
\--- junit:junit:4.12 FAILED

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
\--- junit:junit:4.12 FAILED

runtimeElements - Elements of runtime for main. (n)
No dependencies

runtimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
No dependencies

testCompile - Dependencies for source set 'test' (deprecated, use 'testImplementation ' instead).
\--- junit:junit:4.12 FAILED

testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
\--- junit:junit:4.12 FAILED

testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'test'.
No dependencies

testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies

testRuntime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'test' (deprecated, use 'testRuntimeOnly ' instead).
\--- junit:junit:4.12 FAILED

testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
\--- junit:junit:4.12 FAILED

testRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies
```

Why are there the **FAILED** dependencies?
And what does *deprecated, use 'implementation' instead* mean?

I also used:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

but the same command returns still **FAILED** part: `testCompileClasspath` and `testRuntimeClasspath`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't defined a `repositories` block gradle will print the dependency and marked it as `FAILED`, since it hasn't been resolved correctly (there was no placed defined from where the dependency could have been fetched).

When it comes to `compile` vs `implementation` have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle) please.