# Android Gradle - What to use instead of compileOnly?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

According to the following SO post, `compile` has become `implementation` recently: [What's the difference between implementation and compile in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)

My question is what should I use instead of `compileOnly`? The post above does not address that gradle config. I do know that I can still use `compileOnly` but what is the recommended config that will not be deprecated soon?

It seemed like all configs that contain `..compile..` would be replaced by `..implementation..`. I tried `implementationOnly` but not accepted by Android Studio.

Comment: Not all `..compile..` would be replaced by `..implementation..` such as `api`.

Comment: You can extend your question with this "I don't have compile statement in my dependency. Even thou, when the application is building, the error is still there: 'compile' is obsolete...", if that is also the problem.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`compileOnly` *is* the replacement — the equivalent configuration that is being deprecated is `provided`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations).

Comment: I don't have compile statement in my dependency. Even thou, when the application is building, the error is still there: 'compile' is obsolete...

Comment: @CommonsWare : Every day I'm getting benefited because of you. Thanks a lot for your contributions :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your Project gradle dependecies should be changed from

```
dependencies {
    provided 'com.someDependency:api:78'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.someDependency:api:78'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a case when you accept IDE automatic suggest to add project to your gradle file, it will add "compile project(path: 'xxx')". Correct it and you'll be fine.