# Gradle build error in AndroidStudio 3.0

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have replaced **compile** with **implementation** everywhere in my build.gradle file, still getting this warning **"Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.**" when building the project.

```
dependencies {

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${android_support_lib_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${android_support_lib_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${android_support_lib_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${android_support_lib_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:${android_support_lib_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${android_support_lib_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:${android_support_lib_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${google_play_services_client_library_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${google_play_services_client_library_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${google_play_services_client_library_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:${google_play_services_client_library_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${google_play_services_client_library_version}"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2"
    implementation "de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0"

}
```

Comment: Post the build.gradle file

Comment: @PriyankMehta its not an error. Its a warning in building the project.

Comment: @SamuelRobert Updated the question

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project and rebuilding?

Comment: @SamuelRobert yes several times. but no result.

Comment: @SamuelRobert Can this be because of any of these dependencies?

Comment: Go to this link for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle

Comment: @SamuelRobert I have already replaced **compile** with **implementation** in my build.gradle. It still shows this warning.

Comment: I am also getting this warning after removing all instance of "compile" with instrumentation.

Comment: @JPM Did you find any reason/solution to it?

Comment: @shruti Sorry for the late response. I tried running the gradle build with the debug flag and in my instance it was the version of Google Analytics that produced that warning. I haven't had time to investigate further seeing as how Google Analytics is/has transitioned to Firebase Analytics and I think there is more config to do for that.

Comment: @JPM Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @shruti Was Google Analytics the reason for your warnings as well? Have you updated to Firebase Analytics instead?

Comment: Sorry @JPM, for replying late, I didn't update to Firebase Analytics. Did you get a chance to look further into this?