# Cordova + WorkManager exception

Tags: android, cordova, android-workmanager

I choose WorkManager to make a scheduled service that would help me post data to server when cordova based app is closed.

So, I start with including dependencies in build.gradle (Module:app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    //THIS LINE HERE IS FOR WORKMANAGER
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha01"

    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Now I run following commands

```
cordova clean
cordova build android
```

I get throw with an exception:

> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
> >     dex

So, I add this line

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        //THIS LINE HERE
        multiDexEnabled true

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
```

I ran the clean and build commands again.
Now, I get new exception:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\hjhkjn\Desktop\cordova\hjhkjnad\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\hjhkjn\Desktop\cordova\hjhkjnad\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\19.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [19.jar:android/support/v4/content/PermissionChecker$PermissionResult.class]))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

EDIT:
I do get this error aswell
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question if anyone faces this issue.

I did what was mentioned in this SO question:

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185549/unable-to-merge-dex-when-using-room
//adding the following to the root level of the Gradle file

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for Cordova there is a [Multidex Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-enable-multidex) while you probably just could edit the file which generates the `build.gradle` and enable it there... in order not to install that plugin, which does not have much purpose, but adding those two lines - which only applies for Android and no other platform.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

see [Enable multidex for apps with over 64K methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex).

building against API level > 21 should also work, because there it would be enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin.
Unfortunately that didn't work.
I have added an update to my question with a screenshot.