# Google Fit Android plug-in for Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, jar, aar, google-fit

I am relatively new to Android development and Unity and I am trying to create an Android plug-in for Unity3D that detects steps and distance using the Google fit Sensors API. I have already exported my plugin as a jar file, imported in on Assets/Plugin/Android together with my AndroidManifest.xml and when I try to build and run on my phone I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.OnDataPointListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.me.androidstepcounterplugin-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.me.androidstepcounterplugin-2/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.example.me.androidstepcounterplugin-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

I am guessing that Unity cannot find the Google Fit library, which I added as a dependency on my Android Gradle file. Is there a way to add this in Unity or would it make more sense to try making an aar file instead of jar?

Answer (score 0):

I could think of 2 possible scenarios:

1. You run [proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) on your library with "minify enabled" which cuts that class (because you don't reference it anywhere in your activity). In this case tell proguard to [keep the class](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-code) by adding to your proguard.properties file the following line:

   > -keep class "com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.OnDataPointListener"
2. You are using [`implementation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle) setting for you Fit dependency therefore not including it in the output. Try adding the same dependency to your Unity project.

Comment: Neither of the two, still can't figure out what am I doing wrong

Comment: @slwjc I forgot the "-keep" command in the example. Try with it. I don't have any other ideas...