# DrawerLayout and NavigationView - attribute 'menu' not found

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, drawerlayout

I'm trying to add a Navigation Menu to an existing project in Android Studio. However, while following the instructions on [the official website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html), I added a `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ...` tag around the rest of my view, and under the main ConstraintLayout that has the main activity layout, I put the sample Navigation Draw underneath that:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

The last line causes some problems though when building:

```
Error:error: attribute 'com. ... :menu' not found.
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. The `app` part of `app:menu` is defined in the DrawerLayout tag as: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

This seems to also have the effect of giving me the error `Cannot resolve symbol R` in my MainActivity.java file.

Anyway, any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have the `compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'` in your build.gradle file?
If not, try to add it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked to get rid of the error. I did get another one, however, which I solved by creating the res/menu directory and putting a `my_navigation_files.xml` file inside it.

Comment: If you are using gradle 3.0 use implement instead of compile.
More on the topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/8700123

Comment: if you are using AndroidX: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`