# Why do I get error after changing "compile" to "implementation" in gradle.build?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-dependencies

This is my gradle.build file in one of the modules in the project now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.dropbox.core', name: 'dropbox-core-sdk', version: '3.0.6', changing: true
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar', 'libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
}
```

and these are the errors I get now (don't have it if I change to compile):

> error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist import
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>   public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment

And many many more.

If compile is being deprecated, why is implementation behaving so different?

Comment: Is the question how to fix those errors or why the implementation is behaving differently? (Not that I would know either)

Comment: How to fix them. I understand the concept. Or at least I thought I did.

Comment: Would `api` work instead of `implementation`? Idea based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48141634/2550406)