# Android: library project with Retrofit results in NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, gradle, retrofit2, maven-publish

I'm trying to build an android library project which uses OkHttp and Retrofit to grant access to our REST-backend.

It seems to be working as long as I use `api` instead of `implementation` on my gradle-dependency for `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson`. It seems that this is the only dependency needing this (all others can used with `implementation`).

When using `implementation` here as well, the calling app will crash with `NoClassDefFoundError`:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;

---

I'm using `consumerProguardFiles` with a bunch of proguard-rule-files (e.g. one for okhttp3, retrofit2 etc. from this [repo](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets)). All this will then be packed into an AAR, so rules from the dependencies should be added as well.

It seems that I'm missing a proguard-rule for `converter-gson`. Can somebody post the rules needed to use `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson` in a library project?

---

### Edit 1

My [current proguard-rule](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-retrofit2.pro) for retrofit is:

```
# Retrofit 2.X
## https://square.github.io/retrofit/ ##

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

As mentioned, this seems not enough. Maybe I need something else for `converter-gson`!?

### Edit 2

My dependencies look like this:

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
```

And I'm trying to get rid of the `api` on the last one as I do not need it in the app using this library (or is this not avoidable)?

---

### Edit 3

Hmm, maybe proguard is the wrong keyword. Actually the problem lies in the use of `implementation` over `api`. So dependencies will not be exposed to consumers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/2170109.

But I don't get why I need to expose `converter-gson` to consumers of my library when only the library calls `GsonBuilder`?

Comment: Who's downvoting? This might be OK when there is an easy to find solution but the answers right now are not solving this :-/

Comment: Hmm, maybe proguard is the wrong keyword. Actually the problem lies in the use of `implementation` over `api`. So dependencies will not be exposed to consumers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/2170109

Comment: But I don't get why I need to expose `converter-gson` to consumers of my library when only the library calls `GsonBuilder`?

Answer (score -1):

As per official retrofit github link :

https://github.com/square/retrofit

Retrofit requires at minimum Java 7 or Android 2.3.

If you are using ProGuard you need to add the following options:

```
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain service method parameters.
-keepclassmembernames,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
# Ignore annotation used for build tooling.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# My personal proguard configuration for ratrofit2
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
```

please check once your configuration if there is any mistake :

app-> build.gradle

```
// retrofit gson

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

If there is more error you can share your error log to explain you what exactly problem is.

Comment: The official rules for Retrofit seem different then mine (see edit in the question). But the "new" rules do not work either. Maybe I need something else for `converter-gson`?

Comment: Hmm, maybe proguard is the wrong keyword. Actually the problem lies in the use of implementation over api. So dependencies will not be exposed to consumers. See stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/2170109. But I don't get why I need to expose `converter-gson` to consumers of my library when only the library calls `GsonBuilder`?