# Android: library project with play-services-auth results in NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, maven-publish

(This is basically the same question as in [Android: library project with Retrofit results in NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49030115/2170109) but for `play-services-auth`).

---

I'm trying to build an android library project which uses play-services-auth to access SmartLock for Passwords.

It seems to be working as long as I use `api` instead of `implementation` on my gradle-dependency for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth`. It seems that this is the only dependency needing this (all others can used with `implementation`).

When using `implementation` here as well, the calling app will crash with `NoClassDefFoundError`:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$Builder;

---

I'm using `consumerProguardFiles` with a bunch of proguard-rule-files (e.g. one for okhttp3, retrofit2 etc. from this [repo](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets)). All this will then be packed into an AAR, so rules from the dependencies should be added as well.

It seems that I'm missing a proguard-rule for `play-services-auth`. Can somebody post the rules needed to use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth` in a library project?

Comment: Does it work if you disable proguard?

Comment: Hmm, maybe proguard is the wrong keyword. Actually the problem lies in the use of `implementation` over `api`. So dependencies will not be exposed to consumers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/2170109. But I don't get why I need to expose `play-services-auth` to consumers of my library when only the library calls SmartLock-features?

Comment: Did your change fix it?

Comment: No, no solution yet. I've just realized that it has nothing to do with proguard. But I still don't know why I need to expose `play-services-auth` outside my library.