# databinding error after updating gradle to 4.4 when android studio updated to 3.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I've updated Android Studio to 3.1 from 3.0 and gradle is updated from 3.1 to 4.4 : https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

I'm getting `1 error` and `1 warning`:

**Error:**

```
Cause: couldn't make a guess for com.example.example.databinding.ContentApplicationBinding
```

**Warning:**

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018
```

How can I get it to run as before ?

Answer (score 0):

In your app/build.gradle within `dependencies {...}` you should change from (for example): `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'` to `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'`

For the longer answer see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)

Comment: I've changes all **compile** to **implementation** I still get the same error!