# Android gradle replacing 'compile' with 'api' causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.1

As of gradle 3.0 the `compile` configuration is deprecated. According to the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) and the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle) question, when writing `build.gradle` dependencies `api` should have the same functionality as the old `compile`.

I have an Android library and changing `compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.8'` to `api 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.8'` causes the applications using it to crush with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to instantiate a `WebSocketClient`. So does changing it to `implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.8'`.

The only working solution so far seems to be requesting the applications to add `implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.8'` to their dependencies but I would like to avoid it.

How can I keep the same functionality without using the deprecated `compile`?