# Build error while compling sugar ORM

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, sugarorm

I am trying to compile `sugar ORM` to my application.But it is showing this build error.

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4.

How can I resolve it?Did I miss any other thing to add in gradle?

Comment: Solved!i changed the sugar version to 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your app module's `build.gradle` file from:

```
implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
```

*Note: You may be using `compile` instead. This is [now deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle).*

The current version can always be seen on the [repo's page](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar).

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have already solved that issue :)