# Conflict with dependency : build.gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I added a new dependency

```
compile 'com.github.markomilos:paginate:0.5.1'
```

but after synchronization build, I have an error

> "Conflict with dependency com.android.support:support-annotations'"

here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.formation.mvpnewproject"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.markomilos:paginate:0.5.1'

}
```

[a screenshot on the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uTv1.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Share content of `build.gradle(Project:ProjectName)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add android test dependency

`androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'`

and replace compile with implementation

`implementation 'com.github.markomilos:paginate:0.5.1'`

because the compile configuration is now deprecated and should be replaced by implementation or api for more info about [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Use this into your `build.gradle(app)` file as top level.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
}
```

**like:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    .......
    .......
}

configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    ........
    .......
}
```