# Gradle multiproject multiple dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a gradle project like this:

```
root
  |
  |---- projectA
  |
  |---- projectB
 ...
```

My root build.gradle contains dependencies which are needed for projectA and projectB. I have defined them like this:

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
        compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
```

Now I am trying to add a dependency on projectA from projectB so my projectB build.gradle looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':projectA')
}
```

and projectB settings.gradle:

```
include ':projectA'
project(':projectA').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../projectA')
```

This is currently failing, as projectA and B do not depend on root to get their needed dependencies.

Can I add another dependency from projectA on root or what is the default gradle approach to share same dependencies from one root project?

Answer (score 1):

Your modules (A and B) are not correctly setup as child modules of the root project.
In your base folder, create if necessary the `settings.gradle` file, and add the child modules definition:

**root/settings.gradle**

```
include 'projectA', 'projectB'
```

The `build.gradle` file of projectB is ok as it is, then you need to remove the `root/projectB/settings.gradle` file; child-modules and their locations are specified in the parent build file.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying dependencies with the "compile" keyword is being deprecated.  The new keyword to use is "implementation".  (See [this SO question for an example of explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle).)  The difference between "compile" and "implementation" as it relates to your case, is that "compile" propagates the dependency to all connected modules, while "implementation" is single-level.  So, if you have

```
root
  module A
  module B
```

and module B has a depandency brought in with "compile", then root has access to that dependency.
But if you now change B to bring the dependency in with "implementation", then you'll still need to add the dependency to the root project's build.gradle.

Why is this relevant?  Because a child module isn't allowed to know who its parent is.  So, while A and B both see the dependencies you brought into root, they really shouldn't -- seeing those dependencies is a quirk of how Studio works.  This is also why the answer to "Can I add another dependency from projectA on root" is "no, you're out of luck there, it'd create a circular dependency and that's not allowed".

The dependencies I'd try are:

In both module A and module B:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
  implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
```

Then in Module B, you do:

```
implementation project(':projectA')
```

Then in root, you depend on both A and B.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. So that means when using another module as a dependency, I am not able to specify the same dependency libraries for module A and B inside the root's build.gradle? I really want to make sure I am using the same version of each library on all modules and I am trying to avoid maintaining all implementations separately for each module.

Comment: Good question.  I don't know.  I know that, sometimes, when dependencies don't match, Studio will complain at you in a yellow warning and let you fix it.  But I don't know if that's guaranteed.  I'm a beginner with gradle, so there may be a way to factor dependencies out into a separate file, and keep including that file, but I don't know it.  You can also use a service such as Nexus.  You put your dependencies into Nexus, and pull them down with gradle.  That way, if you have a version that's not matching what's up on the server, you'll have a visible fail.

Comment: However, while the setup you're working on is exactly like one I've recently researched for my project, the details of doing it better are beyond my ken for right now.

Comment: Okay, thanks for coming back on this. I might then ask another question for it.