# I Can't Generate Signed APK For This Error: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: android, gradle

I Can't Generate Signed APK For This Error:

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation' and 'api'

please help me how to fix this problem?

gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.gurujibd.ajkerkhobor"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle Read up

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

into

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```