# Build gradle failed in Android studio 3.1.3

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm running into this error building gradle:

> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

**build.grandle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.edwardraff:JSAT:0.0.9'
}
```

**grandle-wrapper.properties**:

```
#Sun Sep 02 12:44:30 CEST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
```

HOw could I fix it?

Comment: Did you try all suggestions from gradle exception stack trace?Try to Invalidate caches/ Restart...

Comment: Given suggestions are clear, please try them firstly.

Comment: I've tried all suggestion. Building grandle files anyway and show me the same errors.

Comment: What happens when you follow the suggestions given in the error message?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice start building and it stop again showing the same messages

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work or not but replace "compile" with "implementation". 
Check this out: [What's the difference between implementation and compile in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)