# Issue in running React Native app on android studio emulator

Tags: android-studio, react-native, expo

I am running into issues for getting my react native app on Android Studio Emulator

Before I post the problem statement, here is what I have

- Java SE Development Kit 8
- JAVA_HOME path variable is set
- npm install -g expo-cli
- expo init AwesomeProject
  (Sample app works fine in EXPO app using QR code scan)
- yarn eject AwesoneProject
- Opened Android Project in Android Studio
- Created Virtual Device in AVD Manager
- Installed Android SDK Platforms (7.0 - 8.1). For running Virtual device on 7.0 and my android device which is on 8.1
- Settings on my build.gradle file. Please note the google() dependency in All dependency section, this was to get rid of one error. I don't remember what it was, solution was over web
- build.gradle file

> buildscript {
>
> ```
> repositories {
>     jcenter()
>     google()
> }
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
> } }
> ```
>
> allprojects {
>       repositories {
>
> ```
>     mavenLocal()
>     jcenter()
>     google()
>     maven {
>         url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
>     }
> } }
> ```

========Errors I see===========

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'implementation' and 'api'.

I don't know how to solve this so I ignored this warning

- npm run android
  Gives following errors

Some discussions suggests the Expo cli leaves behind following dependency causing it - "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz".
Also it doesn't gives index.js file, can this be linked?

Any suggestions how to get it running?
Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Android Studio Erros]

Answer (score 0):

With gradle 3 'compile' is now obsolete. It has been replaced with 'implementation'. Go to your android/app/build.gradle and inside of the dependencies object change compile to implementation then build again.

A more detailed breakdown has been answered here [What's the difference between implementation and compile in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)

Comment: Hi @Chris - This takes away the warning. Thank You for that solution. Any suggestion on the errors?

Comment: @Raj, can you provide your package.json and android/app/build.gradle  file?

You might want to clear out node_module and any caches. Try this:
Delete ./node_modules,
npm cache clean --force,
cd android & ./gradlew clean,
yarn install.

Then try to build again. Make sure to kill your Metro builder process. I always have some issue with something sticking around during a larger changes

Answer (score 0):

Update your `build.gradle` like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mahdi-  I am not sure which problem this would solve, can you please provide more details?