# How To fix Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018

Tags: android

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018 (How To fix)?

```
dependencies {
    implementation  fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:2.6.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation  'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation  'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    implementation  'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.2'
    implementation  'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation  'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
    implementation  'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-commons:2.6.3@aar'
    implementation  'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions:2.6.3@aar'
    implementation  'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation  'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    implementation  'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7'
    implementation  'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1'
    implementation  'com.fnp:material-preferences:0.1.4'
    implementation  'com.thebluealliance:spectrum:0.7.1'
    implementation  'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    // Required only if Facebook login support is required
    implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')

    // Required only if Twitter login support is required
    implementation ("com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0@aar") { transitive = true }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between implementation and compile in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Replace compile with implementation in :

```
compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:2.6.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: Try replacing compile with api