# ClassNotFoundException for mixed java and kotlin code when running from command line

Tags: java, gradle, command-line, kotlin, compilation

I have mixed `Java` & `Kotlin` code in a demo project which I want to run from `command line`. For only java, I am able to run the program with `java -jar foo.jar` but when I use any class from `Kotlin` code, **it generates `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics`**

I have tried different solutions and checked the `jar` file. It contains both the classes but I guess `kotlin-runtime` is missing from jar.

Here is **build.gradle** file

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.mallaudin.App'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory()? it: zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Content of generated `jar` file

```
.
├── com
│   └── mallaudin
│       ├── App.class
│       └── User.class
└── META-INF
    ├── basics.kotlin_module
    └── MANIFEST.MF
```

Content of `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.mallaudin.App
```

Exception I get when I run `jar` form command line

```
allaudin@geek ~/Desktop/KotlinLab (master) $ java -jar basics/build/libs/basics.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at com.mallaudin.User.<init>(User.kt)
    at com.mallaudin.App.main(App.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Don't use images. Copy and paste the text in your question.

Comment: Can you please post the dependencies part of your build.gradle? I assume the kotlin runtime is not defined as a compile time dependency.

Comment: @ErikPragt kindly check updated question.

Comment: @ErikPragt I think the same but I have added the dependency. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: This is probably a pretty clear writeup" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found a solution. In `build.gradle` file **I have replaced `implementation` configuration with `compile`** and it works now. I believe it should work with `implementation` too but it doesn't. Now the `jar` looks like this

```
.
├── com
├── kotlin
├── META-INF
└── org
```

Comment: Hi, I'm glad it works now, but that's what I said in my previous comment already ;-)

Comment: But why it doesn't work with `implementation`? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will work with implementation too, but then you need to change this line: `configurations.compile` to also include implementation: `configurations.implementation`. Right now, you only include compilation scope, cause that was the 'old' way of doing things.

Comment: `configurations.implementation` is not allowed. I have checked it already.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Switching from `implementation` to `api` didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in the way you build your fat jar. While you use the more recent and recommended `implementation` scope for your dependencies, you are only adding to the fat jar the content of the `compile` configuration.

You should replace the configuration to be used in the fat jar by `runtimeClasspath` which is the full set of runtime components.

That is:

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.mallaudin.App'
  }
  from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {
      it.isDirectory()? it: zipTree(it)
    }
  }
}
```

Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations) to understand the different dependency configurations for a java project.