# How to include runtimeOnly dependency in a Library project which will be consumed as aar in my Application

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to include runtimeOnly dependency in an android library project, which has to be consumed by android app project. Now, when i declare runtimeOnly in android library project. Those dependencies are not available as part of apk

Answer (score 0):

You are using `implementation` or `api`?

According to your description you should use `api` in your library project, `api` will expose the dependency to the `consumer` in your situation `consumer` is your app project.

Here is the duplicate question this may help you. [Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/4593755) [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48388463/4593755)

Comment: I am using runtimeOnly in my library project as defined in [gradle configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management)

Comment: Take a look the link i have pasted [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48388463/4593755),  may be it will help you