# How to include jar dependency from module

Tags: android, gradle

I have an app in that there is a module(mylib). I have included the library in my app with

```
implementation project(path: ':mylib')
```

The problem is in that module there is another `service.jar` dependency which contains `FetchDataActivity.java` when I extend that class in my app with any Activity its giving error

> can not access FetchDataActivity
>   class file for org.service.FetchDataActivity not found

but I'm able to access that class in module(mylib) classes.

I tried to copy that service.jar and added in-app gradle then it's giving duplicate class error while building.

Comment: open your `settings.gradle`

Comment: yeah then what to do @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: check you added  `include` :mylib or not

Comment: include ':app', ':mylib' is there

Comment: found solution instead of **implementation** i used **api** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)