# Creating a fat jar using Kotlin and Gradle - compile vs implementation?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm tinkering with a simple "hello world" project in Kotlin & Gradle (see below). I've added the "fat jar" collection stuff to bring in the Kotlin dependency, but when I try to run `java -jar build/libs/hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` I get the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics` error because the dependencies aren't available at runtime.

I've solved that problem by changing `implementation` to `compile`, which makes everything work fine. But from what I understand, we shouldn't be using `compile` anymore, and neither `api` nor `implementation` makes the "fat jar" collection process work, and as I look at the other options for `dependencies` I'm not sure which to use.

**Question**: what's the "right" thing to do in a case like this?

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.41'
}

group 'com.example.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // if I change "implementation" to "compile", running the jar works
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "ApplicationKt"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

```
// Application.kt
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("hello world")
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle

Comment: Keep `implementation`, but switch to `configurations.compileClasspath.collect`

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet! Would you please submit this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compile` dependency is deprecated. You should use `implementation` to declare your implementation dependencies, and `compileClasspath` to get all the compilation dependencies.