# How to solve Android Studio warning Error?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

when I built my android studio project it shows a message

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
    It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
    Affected Modules: app

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/CircleImageView-master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'


}
```

[image]

Comment: error says it all. replace compile in your gradle with implementation or api

Comment: in you are not getting it please post your gradle file

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle

Comment: The `compile` configuration is now deprecated and should be replaced by `implementation` or `api`

Comment: check post again Sir I already did it

Comment: What android studio version you are using? If you are not using latest version then upgrade it to latest version then error will be gone .

Comment: Rashid yes i updated my android version how to upgrade gradle?

Comment: Post also the build.gradle file in the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's your code warning. it's showing because google will remove `'compile'` support after 2019. It is giving you warning if you are using it please replace it with `'implementation'`. So if you are not using `'compile'` then you do not need to worry about this warning.

Comment: yes, @MIH, that's what I am saying, you have already replaced it with 'implementation' then you don't need to worry about this warning it will automatically remove after 2019.

Comment: but for now what i will do my gradle not built completely?

Comment: it's warning it shouldn't affect your Gradle building

Comment: due to this my Gradle not built completely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200212/discussion-between-mih-and-harsh-shah).

Answer (score 1):

In `build.gradle` (App level),
replace `compile` with `implementation`

And if you are using `implementation` then do not worry about that warning.