# Gradle to use a jar-with-dependencies in compile task

Tags: java, gradle, compiler-errors, build.gradle, gradlew

We have a project that make use of 'jrs-rest-java-client', version: '6.3.1'

The site we used to get the jar from has a certificate issue since September. https://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com

We then had to get the jar from a different site.
https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/

The problem is that a dependency require is missing, but if we use the jar that has "-jar-with-dependencies" it is working. I tried by downloading that jar locally and changing the .gradle to use the local version.

What I would prefer is to have the build to fetch that version directly without having to download first.

How do we specify what jar to use?

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'lib',
    includes: [
        'ojdbc8.jar',
     ])
    //compile group: 'com.jaspersoft', name: 'jrs-rest-java-client', version: '6.3.1'
    compile group: 'com.jaspersoft', name: 'jrs-rest-java-client', version: '6.3.1', USETHISONE: 'jar-with-dependencies'
    //compile files("${buildDir}/jrs-rest-java-client-6.3.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar")
}
```

I have now tried as suggested;

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // to handle broked jasper reports dependencies
    maven {
        url 'http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2'
        url 'https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/'
        url "https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jaspersoft-clients-releases"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':common:project-common-properties')
    implementation project(':common:project-common-mail')

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: [
        'ojdbc8.jar'
     ])
    implementation group: 'com.jaspersoft', name: 'jrs-rest-java-client', version: '6.3.1', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies'
}
```

I'm still getting errors at build time...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':services:notificationService:compileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:jasperserver-dto:6.3.0.
  Required by:
      project :services:notificationService > com.jaspersoft:jrs-rest-java-client:6.3.1
```

That library is not required if the jrs-rest-java-client-6.3.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar is used.

Thanks all,

The solution was, as seen if the video (Thanks!) 
adding a new url:

```
 url "https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jrs-ce-releases"
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are not able to download `jrs-rest-java-client` using gradle. Am I right ?

Comment: @Sambit your maven block is wrong. It should only contain one `url` in there. If you want multiple declare multiple, maven repos each with its own url.

Comment: I tried that well with same results..

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't get that error you get when I use `jrs-rest-java-client-6.3.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. Something else must be requesting that dependency.

Comment: could it be... other sub-project might be... but its ok now as I use the standard jar but included the proper repository and it works.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [jfrog repo](https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/jaspersoft-clients-releases/com/jaspersoft/jrs-rest-java-client/6.3.1/jrs-rest-java-client-6.3.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar), it shows you how to do this:

```
compile(group: 'com.jaspersoft', name: 'jrs-rest-java-client', version: '6.3.1', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies')
```

Add the repo for gradle:

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        name "jaspersoft-releases"
        url "https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jaspersoft-clients-releases"
    }
}
```

I'd recommend [switching from `compile` to `implementation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle) and using a shorthand to declare the dependency:

```
implementation "com.jaspersoft:jrs-rest-java-client:6.3.1:jar-with-dependencies"
```

---

> **Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach him how to fish and you feed him for his life time.**

I decided to record a short clip of how I found the appropriate repositories for the artifacts you needed, on jfrog:

[image]

Comment: Still issues with "Could not find com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:jasperserver-dto:6.3.0."

Comment: @AndreCouture see my edit on how to find the appropriate repositories for the jfrog artifacts you wanted