# why android moved from compile to implementaion

Tags: android

After updating to Android Studio 3.0 and creating a new project, I noticed that in build.gradle there is a new way to add new dependencies instead of compile there is implementation and instead of testCompile there is testImplementation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between implementation and compile in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is okay. It is meant to be this way and you should use the newer keywords. 
Here you can find more ways od declaring dependencies 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html