# Which compile function does gradle need?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm following [a guide for using the WebClient class](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient) in my kotlin project. I'm using gradle as my build tool, so per the "Building with Gradle" section:

[image: gradle instructions]

I added the compile line to my dependencies:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
}
```

*I'm using the kotlin dsl instead of the groovy dsl*

When I do it wants me to import the compile function. Makes sense, though I don't know *which* compile function it's expecting.

[image: compile function imports]

My assumption was that it was the fourth one down coming from the gradle package, but considering it's for use with a JSON pointer it seems wrong (plus I tried importing it to see and it didn't build correctly).

Which compile is gradle expecting? It seems like it should be a simple question that's easy to find the answer for, but searching through the docs and the internet for specifics on a function named `compile`, even with the context of use within the gradle build tool, is an apparent wild goose chase.

Comment: [The `compile()` dependency container was removed in Gradle 7](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#sec:configuration_removal). `compile()` should usually be replaced with `implementation()`, but it can also be replaced with `api()` https://stackoverflow.com/q/44493378/4161471

Comment: Aaaah ok awesome. Thanks for letting me know. I'm new to gradle (and still a bit new to java/kotlin) so I def appreciate the head's up and additional context. Thanks!